# Spring Config: It's not able to locate Config server

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

Config Server `bootstrap.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver

  profiles:
    active: vault

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          host: ${vault_server_host:localhost}
          port: ${vault_server_port:8200}
          scheme: ${vault_server_scheme:https}
          backend: ${vault_backend:configserver}
```

Vault secrets:

```
$ vault kv get configserver/configclient
=== Data ===
Key    Value
---    -----
foo    VAUUULT
```

So, I'm able to get config values using `curl`:

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8888/configclient/default -H "X-Config-Token: f7b238dd-425f-52f8-2104-1e37ecf65ede"
{
   "name":"configclient",
   "profiles":[
      "default"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":null,
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"vault:configclient",
         "source":{
            "foo":"VAUUULT"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So, I've tried to get `foo` value from Config server from Config client. Config client `bootstrap.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configclient
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      headers:
        X-Config-Token: ${vault_token}
```

However, it seems that Config client is not able to locate Config server:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-12 10:03:53.809  INFO 15448 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2018-07-12 10:03:54.239  WARN 15448 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: 400 null
2018-07-12 10:03:54.256  INFO 15448 --- [           main] c.t.i.t.s.t.TdevConfigclientApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

So then, it's getting me that:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'foo' in value "${foo}"

`foo` is configured as `@Value("${foo}")`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class TdevConfigclientApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World! " + this.foo;
    }

    @Value("${foo}")
    private String foo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TdevConfigclientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here you can see a more detailed config client trace snippet:

```
2018-07-12 10:29:05.249  INFO 17299 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2018-07-12 10:29:05.457 DEBUG 17299 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Created GET request for "http://localhost:8888/configclient/default"
2018-07-12 10:29:06.023 DEBUG 17299 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
2018-07-12 10:29:06.092 DEBUG 17299 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@3bb6b7e25 pairs: {GET /configclient/default HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json, application/*+json}{User-Agent: Java/10.0.1}{Host: localhost:8888}{Connection: keep-alive}
2018-07-12 10:29:06.121 DEBUG 17299 --- [           main] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@3b1892d05 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 400}{Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 08:29:06 GMT}{Connection: close}
2018-07-12 10:29:06.145 DEBUG 17299 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : GET request for "http://localhost:8888/configclient/default" resulted in 400 (null); invoking error handler
2018-07-12 10:29:06.162  WARN 17299 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: 400 null
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap.yml you need to replace spring.cloud.config.headers by this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configclient
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      token : ${vault_token}
```

You can see doc http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/1.4.x/single/spring-cloud-config.html